# It's giving an image error in a test I'm running on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The internet image is not being saved in flutter test, is giving this error, I tried using the answers from another question but they didn't work for me

flutter: 00:00 +0: Home screen [E]
flutter:   Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: Home screen
flutter:
flutter: Warning: At least one test in this suite creates an HttpClient. When
running a test suite that uses TestWidgetsFlutterBinding, all HTTP
requests will return status code 400, and no network request will
actually be made. Any test expecting a real network connection and
status code will fail.
To test code that needs an HttpClient, provide your own HttpClient
implementation to the code under test, so that your test can
consistently provide a testable response to the code under test.
flutter: 00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.

**HOMEVIEW**

```
   class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
     const HomeView({super.key});
   
     @override
     State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
   }
   
   class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
   
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: const CsAppBar(
           title: 'Home',
         ),
         body: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: [
             Image.network( 
               'https://thecolor.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/GIF-1.gif',
               width: double.maxFinite,
               height: 400,
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }
```

**HOMEVIEWTEST**

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
   import 'package:network_image_mock/network_image_mock.dart';
   import 'package:para_testes/views/home/home_view.dart';
   
   void main(){
   
     testWidgets('Home screen', (tester) async {
       await mockNetworkImagesFor(() => _createWidget(tester));
   
       final image = find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => widget is Image);
   
       expect(image, findsOneWidget);
   
     });
   }
   
   Future<void> _createWidget(WidgetTester tester) async{
     await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(home: HomeView()));
   
     await tester.pump();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need to test Http connection in widget tests. Just use

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){

  setUpAll(() {
    HttpOverrides.global = null;
  });
...
```

at the beginning of your test. And you will be sure that the Image widget is rendered on the page.

Also you won't need `network_image_mock` package when using the code snippet above

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, it no longer gives any errors but the image ends up not appearing

Comment: You have added this code to your *_test.dart file, right?

Comment: Yes, I added it correctly. I checked now it is giving this error: Invalid image data